# AWS - s3.listobjects suddenly returning Null data object with message "Type Error: cannot read property 'Contents' of null"

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In console I'm getting:

> .../aws-sdk/lib/request.js31 throw err;
>   "Type Error: cannot read property 'Contents' of null"

The following snippet which ***was working perfectly for months*** has all of a sudden begun throwing an error when it tries to read the `data.Contents.length` properties into the `folderLength` variable.

I'm using `aws-sdk` for Node as well as Express4 and socket.io.

All of my AWS credentials are appropriately situated in the .env file

The userID variable is getting set correctly from elsewhere. (Checked with console.log)

The real puzzler is that the app is working fine in the deployed version on Heroku but this problem only seems to be happening when I'm running it through locally.

Any help would be much appreciated...

```
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});

var s3 = new aws.S3();
// name the new AWS folder
var folder = userID + "/";
var s3_params = {
  Bucket: S3_BUCKET,  
  Key: folder, //+ req.query.file_name,   
  Expires: 60,
  ACL: 'public-read' 
};

s3.listObjects({Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Delimiter: '/', Prefix: folder}, function(err, data){
  var folderLength = data.Contents.length;

  //etc etc....
});
```

Comment: Well, you should make sure you are using the correct version of the `aws-sdk` package both on *prod* and on *dev*.

Comment: By 'correct' do you mean most up to date? thanks!

Comment: Yes!, check that versions match. Sometimes an innocent `npm install` or the wrong tag on `package.json` might cause trouble.

Comment: Versions are ok. The app works perfectly on Heroku but can't seem to connect to aws from localhost.

Comment: Could it be wrong policies on S3? Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Comment: Not unless there was some recent change in service. This exact code has been working for months.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your `package.json` file you can show? That might help!

Comment: SOLVED: it was a timing problem. Needed to put   aws.config.update({correctClockSkew: true});   in the global scope

Comment: Whoa! interesting! Glad you could solve it!